# Edit connectionstring of Web.config in webservice (ASPNET)

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I'm using webservice for my Desktop application(C#). I want to edit my database connectionstring programmatically in web.config(in web service) through C#. How to do this? Any simple idea?

Comment: No,... I cannot do that in this way. My application is separate one. It cannot access like this. I found the solution by loading the web.config file as xml and edited. It is working now. Thank u one and all,...

Answer (score 2):

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connName"].ConnectionString = "new connectionstring";
```

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at WebConfigurationManager.